# why mocking mongotemplate.aggregate() returns NullPointerException [Spring Boot Mockito]

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mockito, aggregation

How to mock `mongoTemplate.aggregation().getUniqueMappedResults()`?

Why does the following return `NullPointerException` in `RepoClass`?

```
mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, COLLECTION_NAME,ScreenDetailsEntity.class);
```

I am new to Spring and writing test cases first time. I am highly tired.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

`RepoTestClass`'s `Test` function:

```
  @Test
  public void testValidGetScreenDetails() {
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(
        screenDetailsRepoService, "screenFields",
        ClassUtil.getFieldName(ScreenDetailsEntity.class));
    Aggregation aggregation1 = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        match(where(PAGE).is("Bookings")),
        project(ClassUtil.getFieldName(ScreenDetailsEntity.class)),
        limit(1)
    );

    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = Mockito.mock(MongoTemplate.class);
    Aggregation aggregation = Mockito.mock(Aggregation.class);
    ScreenDetailsEntity screenDetailsEntity = Mockito.mock(ScreenDetailsEntity.class);
    AggregationResults<ScreenDetailsEntity> aggregationResultsMock = Mockito
        .mock(AggregationResults.class);
    Mockito.when(aggregationResultsMock.toString()).thenReturn(new String());
    Mockito.doReturn(aggregationResultsMock).when(mongoTemplate).aggregate(aggregation1, COLLECTION_NAME, ScreenDetailsEntity.class);

    Mockito.doReturn(screenDetailsEntity).when(aggregationResultsMock).getUniqueMappedResult();
    screenDetailsRepoService.getScreenDetails(
        "Bookings", "Web8", "List/View", "en", 45429, 121);
  }
```

RepoClass:

```
public class ScreenDetailsRepoService {

  @Autowired
  private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  private String[] screenFields;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {
    screenFields = ClassUtil.getFieldName(DetailsEntity.class);
  }

  public ScreenDetailsEntity getScreenDetails(final @NonNull String page,
      final @NonNull String client, final String module,
      final String locale, final Integer hotelId, final Integer countryId
  ) throws NoDataFoundException {
    ScreenDetailsEntity screenDetailsEntity;
    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
        match(where(PAGE).is(page)),
        project(screenFields),
        limit(1)
    );
    long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    screenDetailsEntity = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, COLLECTION_NAME, ScreenDetailsEntity.class).getUniqueMappedResult();
    log.info(
        "DB Query: ScreenDetailsRepoService : getScreenDetails - Time taken for db requests : {} milliseconds",
        (System.currentTimeMillis() - t1));
    if (screenDetailsEntity == null) {
      log.error(
          "ScreenDetailsRepoService::getScreenDetails - No data found for for page {} ,module {}, locale {}, hotel {}, country {}",
          page, module, locale, hotelId, countryId);
      throw new NoDataFoundException("No data found");
    }
    return screenDetailsEntity;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same problem you have, and I solved it by mocking the `AggregationResults` from whatever the `aggregate` method was returning, and then I mocked the `getMappedResults()` method of my mocked `AggregationResults` instance. In your case I suppose you would need to mock the `getUniqueMappedResults()`, since that is what you are interested in.

Here's a snippet of my code, this is how I did it:

```java
            // Previously, I have created a List<MyEntity> for testing, that I assigned to a variable called testEntities.
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final AggregationResults<MyEntity> mockResults = (AggregationResults<MyEntity>) mock(
                    AggregationResults.class
            );
            when(mockResults.getMappedResults()).thenReturn(testEntities);
            when(operations.aggregate(any(Aggregation.class), anyString(), eq(MyEntity.class)))
                    .thenReturn(mockResults);
           
            // From here, whenever you call operations.aggregate(...).getMappedResults(), the testEntities list will be retrieved, no NullPointerException given.
```

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the `Aggregation` parameter in mock setup method

```
Mockito.doReturn(aggregationResultsMock).when(mongoTemplate).aggregate(aggregation1, COLLECTION_NAME, ScreenDetailsEntity.class);
```

is not equal to the actual value in the call to `mongoTemplate.aggregate` in `getScreenDetails`. Mockito uses the `equals` method to check if the parameters match and if no matching mock setup is found `null` will be returned as default.

As a first test you could try to mock the method for any Aggregation parameter. E.g.

```
Mockito.doReturn(aggregationResultsMock).when(mongoTemplate).aggregate(Mockito.any(Aggregation.class), Mockito.eq(COLLECTION_NAME), Mockito.eq(ScreenDetailsEntity.class));
```

That way you can check if the Aggregation parameter is causing the issue.

Then you should make sure that the `equals` and `hashCode` methods of the `Aggregation` class are properly implemented.

Comment: *********aggregation value in testValidGetScreenDetails********
Mock for Aggregation, hashCode: 1330912871

Comment: aggregation value in getScreenDetails:
{ "aggregate" : "__collection__", "pipeline" : [{ "$match" : { "page" : "Bookings"}}, { "$project" : { "page" : 1, "module" : 1, "locale" : 1, "resource_id" : 1, { "$sort" : { "order" : 1}}, { "$limit" : { "$numberLong" : "1"}}]}

Comment: Not sure what to do now. Please help further.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Annotations , create a **MongoTemplate** mock and inject it in **ScreenDetailsRepoService** using InjectMock annotation :

```
@Mock
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

@InjectMock
private ScreenDetailsRepoService screenDetailsRepoService;
```

Comment: This worked for me. In addition I had to decorate my test class with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are mocking any method, below are two important considerations,

1. The given parameter to mock method can be `null` in your code. In this case `any()` method won't work, you should go with `nullable()` method
2. The given parameter to mock method is of same type. It is advisable to provide parameter of same type otherwise go with a generic mock.

If you follow these properly you can method in Spring framework. In your case the below mock should work fine.

```
doReturn(someResult)
    .when(mongoTemplate)
    .aggregate(Mockito.nullable(Aggregation.class), Mockito.nullable(String.class), Mockito.<Class<?>> any());
```